# Programing a simple routine in microsoft excel 2007 on windowx xp

Tags: excel, vba

I have minimal experience with coding functions within software platforms (i.e. SPSS syntax, MATLAB scripts, Psychopy coder). Due to this, I have found myself wishing I could code simple routine loops for more general programs. I am hoping that there is a way to do this for excel. Specifically, is there a way I can code excel to: open a file, delete two columns serially, and save that file in a new location with a new file name and repeat this for all of the files in a containing folder? I believe an answer to this question will be very useful for individuals with minimal coding experience that would benefit from a code that runs a simple function in excel automatically without having to point and click in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Excel
2. Turn on the macro recorder
3. Open your first file
4. Delete your two columns
5. Save the file as
6. Stop the macro recorder

This will give you the VBA code you need, then you can wrap a simple loop around it to repeat for all the files in your directory.

Give it a shot, then come back with the code you've got and ask a specific question if you're running into an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to loop through files in a folder and edit text files removing lines, or renaming files, or whatever... check out the [FileScriptingObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

A quick down and dirty vba subroutine where we loop through each file in a folder, open it for reading, open a second file for writing and then write out each line, line for line, skipping lines 5 and 6:

```
Sub FindOpenFiles()

    Const fsoForWriting = 2
    Const fsoForAppend = 8
    Const fsoForReading = 1

    directory = "C:\"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(directory)

    'Loop through files in folder
    For Each file In folder.Files

        'get the file path, open the file and create a new file with "_out" appended to the name
        strFileInName = file.Path
        strFileOutName = file.Path & "_out"
        Set objFileIn = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileInName, fsoForReading)
        Set objFileOut = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileOutName, fsoForWriting, True)

        'Loop through each line in the incoming file
        lineCount = 1
        Do Until objFileIn.AtEndOfStream
            'Write every line out to the output file, except for line 5 and 6
            If lineCount <> 5 Or lineCount <> 6 Then
                objFileOut.WriteLine objFileIn.ReadLine
                lineCount = lineCount + 1
            Next
        Loop
    Next file


End Sub
```

All in all, this subroutine has nothing to do with Excel, so you could stick this in Microsoft Word, Powerpoint, Outlook, and with minimal editing, it's own stand alone vbscript.